# try_lock on futures::lock::Mutex outside of async?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement  `Async` read for a struct that has a `futures::lock::Mutex`:

```
pub struct SmolSocket<'a> {
    stack: Arc<futures::lock::Mutex<SmolStackWithDevice<'a>>>,
}

impl<'a> AsyncRead for SmolSocket<'a>  {
    fn poll_read(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf<'_>
    ) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
        block_on(self.stack).read(...)
    }
}
```

The problem is that, since `poll_read` is not async, I cannot call `await`. But I also don't want to, as it'd block. I could call `try_lock` to try and if not, I'd register a `Waker` to be called by `SmolSocket` in the future.

Since I cannot do that either because it's not `async`, is there a version of `block_on` that does the same as `try_lock` for `futures::lock::Mutex` outside of `async`?

Comment: `block_on` shouldn't be called in a poll function because it, well, blocks. Instead, you can call `self.stack.lock().poll(cx)`. If you get `Poll::Pending`, you need to return `Poll::Pending`, and if you receive `Poll::Ready(x)`, you'll have the unlocked mutex in `x`.

Comment: @user4815162342 there's no `poll` method on `self.stack.lock()`

Comment: @user4815162342 `no method named `poll` found for struct `futures::lock::MutexLockFuture<'_, networking::smol_stack_impl::...>` in the current scope`

Comment: 1. Does `SmolStackWithDevice` implement `Read` or `AsyncRead`? (what is the signature of `read` method on it?)  
2. Is there a reason you are implementing the `tokio`  flavor of `AsyncRead`, but using the `futures` flavor of `Mutex` (as opposed to either both `tokio` or both `futures`)

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean to poll the `MutexLockFuture` instead, this can for example be done with the [`core::task::ready!` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/task/macro.ready.html), which desugars as following:

```rust
let num = match fut.poll(cx) {
    Poll::Ready(t) => t,
    Poll::Pending => return Poll::Pending,
};
```

To poll a future, you also need to pin it (ensure it doesn't get moved). This can be done on the stack with [`tokio::pin!`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.6.0/tokio/macro.pin.html), or `Pin::new` if the type is already `Unpin` (`MutexLockFuture` is), or by moving onto the heap with `Box::pin`.

Below is a runnable example.

**⚠️ KEEP READING TO SEE WHY YOU DON'T WANT TO DO THIS!**

```rust
#![feature(ready_macro)]
use core::{
    future::Future,
    pin::Pin,
    task::{ready, Context, Poll},
};
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::io::{AsyncRead, AsyncReadExt};
pub struct SmolStackWithDevice<'a> {
    counter: usize,
    data: &'a [u8],
}
impl<'a> AsyncRead for SmolStackWithDevice<'a> {
    fn poll_read(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
        if self.counter % 2 == 0 {
            self.counter += 1;
            cx.waker().wake_by_ref();
            println!("read nothing");
            return Poll::Pending;
        }
        buf.put_slice(&[self.data[self.counter / 2]]);
        self.counter += 1;
        println!("read something");
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    }
}
pub struct SmolSocket<'a> {
    stack: Arc<futures::lock::Mutex<SmolStackWithDevice<'a>>>,
}
impl<'a> AsyncRead for SmolSocket<'a> {
    fn poll_read(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
        let mut lock_fut = self.stack.lock();
        let pinned_lock_fut = Pin::new(&mut lock_fut);
        let mut guard = ready!(pinned_lock_fut.poll(cx));
        println!("acquired lock");
        let pinned_inner = Pin::new(&mut *guard);
        pinned_inner.poll_read(cx, buf)
    }
}
#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]
async fn main() {
    let data = b"HORSE";
    let mut buf = [0; 5];
    let mut s = SmolSocket {
        stack: Arc::new(
            SmolStackWithDevice {
                counter: 0,
                data: &data[..],
            }
            .into(),
        ),
    };
    s.read_exact(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
    println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf));
}
```

[**Look at it go!** (in Rust Playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d795708ddf0633ea83ce5b39bc54d1c0)

**⚠️ KEEP READING TO SEE WHY YOU DON'T WANT TO DO THIS!**

So, what is the problem?
Well, as you can see from the output, whenever we succeed in acquiring the lock, but the underlying source is not ready to read, or only gives us a small read, we drop the lock, and on the next poll we will have to acquire it again.

This is a good point to remember that `async` flavors of `Mutex` are only recommended over `std` or `parking_lot` when it is expected that the `Guard` from a successful locking will be held across an `await`, or explicitly stored in a `Future` data structure.

We are not doing that here, we are only ever exercising the fast path equivalent to [`Mutex::try_lock`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/lock/struct.Mutex.html#method.try_lock), because whenever the lock is not immediately available, we drop the `MutexLockFuture` instead of waiting to be waked to poll it again.

However, storing the lock in the data structure would make it easy to accidentally deadlock. So a good design might be creating an awkward-to-store(borrowing) `AsyncRead` adapter that wraps the lock:

```rust
pub struct SmolSocket<'a> {
    stack: Arc<futures::lock::Mutex<SmolStackWithDevice<'a>>>,
}
impl<'a> SmolSocket<'a> {
    fn read(&'a self) -> Reader<'a> {
        Reader::Locking(self.stack.lock())
    }
}
pub enum Reader<'a> {
    Locking(futures::lock::MutexLockFuture<'a, SmolStackWithDevice<'a>>),
    Locked(futures::lock::MutexGuard<'a, SmolStackWithDevice<'a>>),
}
impl<'a> AsyncRead for Reader<'a> {
    fn poll_read(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
        let this = self.get_mut();
        match this {
            Reader::Locking(f) => {
                *this = Reader::Locked(ready!(Pin::new(f).poll(cx)));
                println!("acquired lock");
                Pin::new(this).poll_read(cx, buf)
            }
            Reader::Locked(l) => Pin::new(&mut **l).poll_read(cx, buf),
        }
    }
}
#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]
async fn main() {
    let data = b"HORSE";
    let mut buf = [0; 5];
    let s = SmolSocket {
        stack: Arc::new(
            SmolStackWithDevice {
                counter: 0,
                data: &data[..],
            }
            .into(),
        ),
    };
    s.read().read_exact(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
    println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf));
}
```

[**Look at it go!** (executable Playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3b51d14091e177bbefb97a7b8cf52bdc)

This works out, because both the `LockFuture` and our `SmolStackWithDevice` are `Unpin` (non-self-referential) and so we don't have to guarantee we aren't moving them.

In a general case, for example if your `SmolStackWithDevice` is not `Unpin`, you'd have to project the `Pin` like this:

```rust
unsafe {
    let this = self.get_unchecked_mut();
    match this {
        Reader::Locking(f) => {
            *this = Reader::Locked(ready!(Pin::new_unchecked(f).poll(cx)));
            println!("acquired lock");
            Pin::new_unchecked(this).poll_read(cx, buf)
        }
        Reader::Locked(l) => Pin::new_unchecked(&mut **l).poll_read(cx, buf),
    }
}
```

Not sure how to encapsulate the unsafety, `pin_project` isn't enough here, as we also need to dereference the guard.

But this only acquires the lock once, and drops it when the `Reader` is dropped, so, great success.

You can also see that it doesn't deadlock if you do

```rust
    let mut r1 = s.read();
    let mut r2 = s.read();
    r1.read_exact(&mut buf[..3]).await.unwrap();
    drop(r1);
    r2.read_exact(&mut buf[3..]).await.unwrap();
    println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf));
```

This is only possible because we deferred locking until polling.

Comment: "when it is expected that the Guard from a successful locking will be held across an await, or explicitly stored in a Future data structure." why this is needed?

Comment: @Gatonito when none of the consuming tasks yield without dropping the guard, it is wasteful to set up the waker notification machinery and such. (The assumption is none of the tasks are doing long blocking work, so blocking on the unavailable `Mutex` won't be an issue) See this section of tokio documentation for the horse's mouth: https://docs.rs/tokio/1.6.0/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html#which-kind-of-mutex-should-you-use

Comment: Are you sure your solution of simply locking the guard works? On https://users.rust-lang.org/t/try-lock-on-futures-lock-mutex-outside-of-async/59853/13 I tried the same question and they said it's not that simple

Comment: It's definitely inefficient, and if the Mutex does something like queueing up those who are waiting for it, you may never get a turn (as you keep giving up your spot in line and going to the back of the queue)