# The shared mutex problem in Rust (implementing AsyncRead/AsyncWrite for Arc<Mutex<IpStack>>)

Tags: multithreading, rust, concurrency, mutex

Suppose I have an userspace TCP/IP stack. It's natural that I wrap it in `Arc<Mutex<>>` so I can share it with my threads.

It's also natural that I want to implement `AsyncRead` and `AsyncWrite` for it, so libraries that expect `impl AsyncWrite` and `impl AsyncRead` like `hyper` can use it.

This is an example:

```
use core::task::Context;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::sync::Arc;
use core::task::Poll;
use tokio::io::{AsyncRead, AsyncWrite};

struct IpStack{}

impl IpStack {
    pub fn send(self, data: &[u8]) {
        
    }
    
    //TODO: async or not?
    pub fn receive<F>(self, f: F) 
        where F: Fn(Option<&[u8]>){
        
    }
}

pub struct Socket {
    stack: Arc<futures::lock::Mutex<IpStack>>,
}

impl AsyncRead for Socket {
    fn poll_read(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf<'_>
    ) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
        //How should I lock and call IpStack::read here?
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    }
}

impl AsyncWrite for Socket {
    fn poll_write(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &[u8],
    ) -> Poll<Result<usize, std::io::Error>> {
        //How should I lock and call IpStack::send here?
        Poll::Ready(Ok(buf.len()))
    }
    //poll_flush and poll_shutdown...
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f88f66bf28c13c26fcde416ba3b264d5)

I don't see anything wrong with my assumptions and I don't see another better way to share a stack with multiple threads unless I wrap it in `Arc<Mutex<>>`

This is similar to [try_lock on futures::lock::Mutex outside of async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67551726/try-lock-on-futureslockmutex-outside-of-async/67655040#67655040) which caught my interest.

How should I lock the mutex without blocking? Notice that once I got the lock, the `IpStack` is not async, it has calls that block. I would like to implement async to it too, but I don't know it the problem will get much harder. Or would the problem get simpler if it had async calls?

Answer (score 0):

I found the tokio documentation page on `tokio::sync::Mutex` pretty helpful: https://docs.rs/tokio/1.6.0/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html

From your description it sounds you want:

- Non-blocking operations
- One big data structure that manages all the IO resources managed by the userspace TCP/IP stack
- To share that one big data structure across threads

I would suggest exploring something like an actor and use message passing to communicate with a task spawned to manage the TCP/IP resources. I think you could wrap the API kind of like the `mini-redis` example cited in `tokio`'s documentation to implement `AsyncRead` and `AsyncWrite`. It might be easier to start with an API that returns futures of complete results and then work on streaming. I think this would be easier to make correct. Could be fun to exercise it with [loom](https://github.com/tokio-rs/loom).

I think if you were intent on synchronizing access to the TCP/IP stack through a mutex you'd probably end up with an `Arc<Mutex<...>>` but with an API that wraps the mutex locks like `mini-redis`. The suggestion the `tokio` documentation makes is that their Mutex implementation is more appropriate for managing IO resources rather than sharing raw data and that does fit your situation I think.

Comment: I don't see how `tokio::sync::Mutex` would help because `AsyncRead` is pollable, I have to implement polling in non async way. Also only https://github.com/tokio-rs/mini-redis/blob/c3bc304ac9f4b784f24b7f7012ed5a320594eb69/src/db.rs uses `Mutex` on mini-redis and I don't see any async operation that uses it

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** use an asynchronous mutex for this. Use a standard [`std::sync::Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html).

Asynchronous mutexes like [`futures::lock::Mutex`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/lock/struct.Mutex.html) and [`tokio::sync::Mutex`](https://tokio-rs.github.io/tokio/doc/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html) allow locking to be awaited instead of blocking so they are safe to use in `async` contexts. They are designed to be used across `await`s. This is precisely what you don't want to happen! Locking across an `await` means that the mutex is locked for potentially a very long time and would prevent other asynchronous tasks wanting to use the `IpStack` from making progress.

Implementing [`AsyncRead`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.6.1/tokio/io/trait.AsyncRead.html)/[`AsyncWrite`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.6.1/tokio/io/trait.AsyncWrite.html) is straight-forward in theory: either it can be completed immediately, or it coordinates through some mechanism to notify the context's waker when the data is ready and returns immediately. Neither case requires extended use of the underlying `IpStack`, so its safe to use a non-asynchronous mutex.

```
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::task::{Context, Poll};
use tokio::io::{AsyncRead, AsyncWrite};

struct IpStack {}

pub struct Socket {
    stack: Arc<Mutex<IpStack>>,
}

impl AsyncRead for Socket {
    fn poll_read(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
        let ip_stack = self.stack.lock().unwrap();

        // do your stuff

        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry I don't get it, why locking in the poll_read is ok?

Comment: I'm not sure how better to explain it. If your plan is to wait for results within `poll_read`, you're doing it wrong. Whether the data is immediately available to be read or not, the function should return quickly. And since that is the goal, a blocking mutex fits nicely.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't see another better way to share a stack with multiple threads unless I wrap it in `Arc<Mutex<>>`.

A `Mutex` is certainly the most *straightforward* way to implement something like this, but I would suggest an inversion of control.

In the `Mutex`-based model, the `IpStack` is really driven by the `Socket`s, which consider the `IpStack` to be a shared resource. This results in a problem:

- If a `Socket` blocks on locking the stack, it violates the contract of `AsyncRead` by spending an unbounded amount of time executing.
- If a `Socket` *doesn't* block on locking the stack, choosing instead to use `try_lock()`, it may be starved because it doesn't remain "in line" for the lock. A fair locking algorithm, such as that provided by `parking_lot`, can't save you from starvation if you don't wait.

Instead, you might approach the problem the way the system network stack does. Sockets are not actors: the network stack drives the sockets, not the other way around.

In practice, this means that the `IpStack` should have some means for polling the sockets to determine which one(s) to write to/read from next. OS interfaces for this purpose, though not directly applicable, may provide some inspiration. Classically, BSD provided [`select(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) and [`poll(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html); these days, APIs like [`epoll(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html)(Linux) and [`kqueue(2)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2)(FreeBSD) are preferred for large numbers of connections.

A dead simple strategy, loosely modeled on `select`/`poll`, is to repeatedly scan a list of `Socket` connections in round-robin fashion, handling their pending data as soon as it is available.

For a basic implementation, some concrete steps are:

- When creating a new `Socket`, a bidirectional channel (i.e. one bounded channel in each direction) is established between it and the `IpStack`.
- `AsyncWrite` on a `Socket` attempts to send data over the outgoing channel to the `IpStack`. If the channel is full, return `Poll::Pending`.
- `AsyncRead` on a `Socket` attempts to receive data over the incoming channel from the `IpStack`. If the channel is empty, return `Poll::Pending`.
- The `IpStack` must be driven externally (for instance, in an event loop on another thread) to continually poll the open sockets for available data, and to deliver incoming data to the correct sockets. By allowing the `IpStack` to control which sockets' data is sent, you can avoid the starvation problem of the `Mutex` solution.

Comment: Indeed, the stack already works like this: https://github.com/lucaszanella/smoltcp/blob/ip-interface-alt-managed/examples/client.rs#L62. There's no concept of sockets, you just pass a handler (just an integer) to the stack so it knoes which socket to send the data through. This stack has a loop that polls all the sockets. This is an example, I could do a more efficient polling, but in general you have to actively poll the sockets.

Comment: I was trying not to use channels as this would lead to memory copies. If I have a video stream for example, I'd be copying the packets from the thread to the stack through a channel, when in the Mutex model I'd simply lock and send to the stack right away.

Comment: So yes, the stack has a polling function, and I can see which ones can be read. However I think when one has data to be read I must read it right away or the data will be overwritten in the next poll.

Comment: Upon trying to implement what you suggested, I noticed that it might not be so simple. For example, when tokio calls `poll_read` and it returns `Poll::Pending`, `tokio` will not call it forever. It may try one or two more times, but then it will not try again and will rely on the `poll_read` function having saved a `Wake` object to call back when it has data. So I think I'll at least need to store a `Waker` locally on every `poll_read` call. Do you agree?